# Proof of indexed cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Could anyone verify if my proof is correct please?
The question is as follows:

> For each $(i,j)\in I\times I$, let $C_{i,j}=A_i\times B_j$, and let $P=I\times I$.
>
> Prove $\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\times \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$

Logical form of the formula: $\forall s (\exists (i,j)\in I\times I(s\in C_{i,j})\iff s\in  \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\times \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i  )$

$\to$:

Let s be an arbitrary ordered pair of the antecedent, i.e. 1) $\exists (i,j)\in I\times I(s\in C_{i,j})$.

We apply existential instantiation to get $(k,l) \in C_{k,l}$, and since $C_{i,j}=A_i\times B_j$, by definition we have 2) $k \in A_i \land l \in B_j \land s=(k,l)$.

On the other hand, the conclusion we need is: $s\in  \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\times \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i  $, which means 3) $\exists x \exists y (\exists i\in I(x\in A_i) \land \exists i\in I (y\in B_i)\land s=(x,y))$.

If we apply existential generalisation on 2) with k and l replaced by x and y respectively, we would get the conclusion.

$\leftarrow$:

Just a matter of applying existential instantiation on 3), i.e. x and y to q and z, i to j, then existential generalising the variables so that it becomes 2). Then one more existential generalisation we will get 1).

---

The reason I am insecure about this is because I am implicitly assuming $s=(i,j)$ when I translate

$\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\times \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$

to

$\forall s (\exists (i,j)\in I\times I(s\in C_{i,j})\iff s\in  \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\times \bigcup_{i\in I} B_i  )$

which I am not sure if it is legit.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: If  $p$ allready denotes an element of indexset $P$ then you better do not use symbol $p$ for elements of any other set. It makes your proof muddled.

Comment: What are $A_i$ and $B_j$?

Comment: @user254665 Sorry for missing that out; $A_i$ and $B_j$ are defined as indexed family of sets, ie. {$A_i |i\in I$} and {$B_i |i\in I$}. It is not mentioned that $j\in I$, but judging from 'For each (i,j)$\in I \times I$', that should be correct

Comment: @user254665 Thank you, I have now changed all p to s, would that make my proof ok?

Comment: In your last  paragraph you are not assuming $ s=(i,j)$ at all . $(i,j)$ belongs to the index set $P$. But $s$ is or ought to be shown to be, $(a_i,b_j).$  Proof lacks details (e.g. "We would get the conclusion.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first and only critique of your proof (because I didn't read it) is that it is unreadable. You want other human beings, and not computers, to be able to read and understand your proof. In particular, writing down quantifiers like that is a big no-no (except perhaps when defining a set very rigorously).

How about this: By definition of union, an element in $\bigcup C_{i,j}$ belongs to some $C_{i,j} = A_i \times B_j \subset \bigcup A_i \times \bigcup B_i$. Conversely, an element in $\bigcup A_i \times \bigcup B_i$ is a pair $(a,b)$ with $a \in \bigcup A_i$ and $b \in \bigcup B_i$. This means that $a \in A_i$ and $b \in B_j$ for some $i,j \in I$. But this is equivalent to $(a,b) \in A_i \times B_j = C_{i,j} \subset \bigcup C_{i,j}$.

Comment: Thank you! It took me quite a while, but I think I finally understand your solution. The only question I have is for 'an element in $\bigcup C_{i, j}$...' - is this legit? Presumably this is the assumption you made from $\bigcup_{p\in P}C_p$ being the antecedent, and since $p \in P$ and $P=I\times I$, it seems that we can infer that $p=i, j$, but I am not sure

Comment: I agree that my proof looks messy, and yours does indeed look a lot more elegant, but I am always very wary of messing up the variables - just like my question above (in fact I encountered the same problem when I was doing my own proof - see my original thread). That's why I tend to write out the whole thing in variables.

I have never received proper maths education (self-studying now) so I don't really know how to do informal proofs while maintaining the correctness of the variables...